# How do I direct all visits to SSL site?

Tags: ssl, seo

I've just bought an SSL certificate for a website purely for the SEO benefits.

What is the best way from an SEO perspective to have all visitors receive the https url rather than the http URL please?

Many thanks,
Andy

Answer (score -1):

The SEO Friendly Redirect is 301 Redirect. You can also read about it here [Change page URLs with 301 redirects](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en) or [Redirection](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection)